# xslt how to change the attribute value of a tag based on attribute value from other tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the below input xml.
Now here I want to change the outputclass of the first topicref inside  only if the name of data tag ="Doctype" and for that value="Datasheet" or "databrief".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">
<bookmap xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/"
         domains="(map bookmap) class="- map/map bookmap/bookmap ">
   <booktitle class="- topic/title bookmap/booktitle ">
      <mainbooktitle class="- topic/ph bookmap/mainbooktitle ">STD10NM60ND, STF10NM60ND, STP10NM60ND</mainbooktitle>
      <booktitlealt class="- topic/ph bookmap/booktitlealt ">N-channel 600 V, 0.57 Ω typ., 8 A, FDmesh™ II Power MOSFETs in DPAK, TO-220FP and TO-220 packages</booktitlealt>
   </booktitle>
   <bookmeta class="- map/topicmeta bookmap/bookmeta ">
      <data name="DocType" value="Datasheet" class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="ProductStatusFootnote"
            value="This is information on a product in full production."
            class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="ProductStatus"
            value="Datasheet - production data"
            class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="Application" value="" class="- topic/data "/>
                <data name="AuthorName" value="" class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="Technology" value="" class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="Package option" value="" class="- topic/data "/>
      <data name="DxParentInfo" value="" class="- topic/data "/>
   </bookmeta>
   <frontmatter toc="no" class="- map/topicref bookmap/frontmatter ">
      <topicref navtitle="@NA"
                toc="no"
                class="- map/topicref "
                href="../Topics/DPAK_TO-220_TO-220FP_coverIMAGE_silhouette.dita">
         <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
            <linktext class="- map/linktext ">Cover image</linktext>
            <searchtitle class="- map/searchtitle ">Cover image</searchtitle>
         </topicmeta>
      </topicref>
      <topicref navtitle="@NA"
                toc="no"
                class="- map/topicref "
                outputclass="Dx:CoverPage"
                href="../Topics/AM01475v1_internalSCHEMATIC_TAB_noZEN.dita">
         <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
            <linktext class="- map/linktext ">Internal schematic diagram</linktext>
            <searchtitle class="- map/searchtitle ">Internal schematic diagram</searchtitle>
         </topicmeta>
      </topicref>
      <topicref navtitle="Features"
                toc="no"
                class="- map/topicref "
                href="../Topics/STP10NM60ND_featuresTABLE.dita">
         <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
            <linktext class="- map/linktext ">Features table</linktext>
            <searchtitle class="- map/searchtitle ">Features table</searchtitle>
         </topicmeta>
      </topicref>
      <topicref navtitle="@NA"
                toc="no"
                class="- map/topicref "
                href="../Topics/PMOS_FDmesh_II_features.dita">
         <topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta ">
            <linktext class="- map/linktext ">Features</linktext>
            <searchtitle class="- map/searchtitle ">Features</searchtitle>
         </topicmeta>
      </topicref>


             </frontmatter>
   <chapter href="DocID18467_STP10NM60ND.ditamap"
            format="ditamap"
            class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter "/>
   <backmatter class="- map/topicref bookmap/backmatter ">
      <amendments class="- map/topicref bookmap/amendments "
                  href="../Topics/STP10NM60ND_revHIST.dita"/>
      <notices href="../../../../../../Corporate/Migration/disclaimer_PUBLIC.dita"
               locktitle="yes"
               navtitle="@NA"
               class="- map/topicref bookmap/notices "/>
   </backmatter>
</bookmap>
```

Thanks to please suggest some solution using xslt.I am able to select the first topicref of the frontmatter but don't know where and how to put the other conditions in it.

Comment: Can you also add the XSLT code that you have written? Also how are `<topicref>` and `<data>` related to each other? Do we refer to the only the 1st `<data>` for the values or any `<data>`?

Comment: We can refer to any data.There are a lot of data tags and their order can vary in different files.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far in XSL.

Comment: You say you want to change the outputclass. How do you want to change it? Rename it, remove it or change its content?